# Laravel 5.8: Weird Error Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to develop my project and in this project, I have a **OneToMany** relationship between `Member` Model & `Student` Model like this:

`Student.php`:

```
public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'std_mbr_id');
    }
```

`Member.php`:

```
public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Student::class,'std_mbr_id');
    }
```

Then at the Controller, I added this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $student = new Student();
        $students = $student->searchStudents()->paginate(20);
        $custom = new Student();
        $customs = $custom->all();
        return view('admin.students.custom', compact('students','customs'));
    }
```

Now at the view I want to get `created_at` timestamp like this:

`$customs->find($student->mbr_id)->created_at`

But this will return this error:

**Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object**

However when I do `dd($customs->find($student->mbr_id))`, I can properly get the timestamps:

[image]

So how to access the `created_at` timestamp in this situation?

---

**UPDATE #1:**

Result of `{{ dd($customs->find($student->mbr_id)->created_at ) }}`:

[image]

Comment: I get *null* as the result of `{{ dd($customs->find($student->mbr_id)->std_mrb_id) }}`

Comment: I just added an **UPDATE #1** about the result of  `{{ dd($customs->find($student->mbr_id)->created_at ) }}`

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Would u mind please help me with this problem, I'm really stuck with this...

Comment: Now you can find the `created_at` object as UPDATE #1.

Comment: Now it is working fine right? as per your Update#1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235476/discussion-between-amit-senjaliya-and-tejoslaeslio).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if `$customs->find($student->mbr_id)` returns something:

```
$customs->find($student->mbr_id) ? $customs->find($student->mbr_id)->created_at : 'not found';
```

Comment: Hey man, I just faced a new problem, would u mind plz help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601648/return-value-of-maatwebsite-excel-sheetmaparrayblerow-must-be-of-the-type-ar